# Python large directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, filesystems, ext4

I'm using python to read directory containing potentially many execution trace files. Each file is usually small (few lines, usually less than 1Ko).

My script reads few hundred of file per seconds, but when the number of file in the directory exceed ~60k, the program slow down and only few files (3/4) are read per second :

```
def read_traces(path: str):
    files = glob.glob("*.ktest")
    traces = []
    for f in files:             
        replay_cmd = "KTEST_FILE=" + f + " ./replay.bc"

        p = sp.Popen(replay_cmd, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, shell=True)
        out, _ = p.communicate()
        trace = Trace(f, out.decode("UTF-8"))
        traces.append(trace)
    return traces
```

Is this a problem with Python, or with the file system (ext3) ? How can I resolve this slow down ?

Comment: It is hard to know without seeing the script. Please post it if you want help.

Comment: use threads or multiprocessing (map/reduce) your problem. don't handle all files in the directory in a sequential manner.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you actually do with each file. Are you performing an operation on the file name, or actually opening it?

Comment: I edited the post with the computation done on files. It's Klee's ktest and I replay the execution trace for each file.